# I can’t use $(this) Jquery

Tags: jquery

Now code is this.

```
<button id=hine onclick=mo('ppp')>Go!</button>
<script>
function mo(name){
  alert(name);
  alert($(this).attr('id')); // undefined
}
</script>
```

How can I use $(this) in jQuery ?

Comment: You should handle the event in function `mo` and use event.target to get the `id`

Comment: Try `$(event.target).attr('id')`

Comment: Barmar's answer should solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `this` as an explicit argument.

```
<button id="hine" onclick="mo(this, 'ppp')">Go!</button>
<script>
function mo(element, name){
  alert(name);
  alert($(element).attr('id')); // undefined
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
function mo(elem, name){
  alert(name);
  alert($(elem).attr('id')); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=hine onclick="mo(this, 'ppp')">Go!</button>
```